# How to display Textures, Buttons, Created with Unity's GUI (OnGUI()) to get displayed behind other objects in Scene

Tags: unity, textures

I am making a game in which I am using OnGUI() to make Texture. I want this texture to display behind my Regular 3D objects like cube, spheres in the scene. I have tried and searched but I am unable to figure it out. Is this Possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any thing drawn by OnGUI will be rendered or drawn in front of all 3d objects.

however if your creating the GUITexture GameObject Then there is a way to do that

The way to do this is to use two cameras. one purely a GUI camera with depth lower than that camera used to render 3d object.

In the 3d cam set the culling mask to the layer on which your 3d objects lie. set this cameras depth to 0.

the GUI camera should be set to depth only(Clear flags) and set its depth to -1.
all the GuiTextures should be on the useer defined layer and set its culling mask to that specific layer.

in the 3d cams culling mask the layer you defined for 2d objects should be unchecked.